# Getting MatrixPropertyDistribution::sclrvctr: error from documentation example

Tags: matrix, probability-or-statistics, warning-messages, distributions

I'm new to StackExchange, but I am having a strange error using just downloaded Mathematica 12.1.1.0 (Student version). I'm trying to use the MatrixPropertyDistribution function, but Mathematica gives me an error even when I use the exact example that it gives in the documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPropertyDistribution.html.

In particular, when I try to copy and paste the first example and try to run it,

```
Mean[
  MatrixPropertyDistribution[Tr[x.x], x \[Distributed] 
    GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[2]]] // N
```

I get the error:

> MatrixPropertyDistribution::sclrvctr: Tr[x. x] should be a scalar or vector expression.

Even if I do the expression:

```
Mean[
  MatrixPropertyDistribution[1, x \[Distributed] 
    GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[2]]] // N
```

I get the absurd sounding error

> MatrixPropertyDistribution::sclrvctr: 1 should be a scalar or vector expression.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Windows 10 with 12.1.1.0 home-edition gives a number that seems to fluctuate between 2.99 and 3.002. Are you sure you haven't accidentally defined `x`? If I define `x=1234` for example, then I get the error. Try `Clear[x]` and run the example again.

Comment: You can also localize x in a Block by doing `Block[{x},Mean[MatrixPropertyDistribution[Tr[x.x], x \[Distributed]GaussianOrthogonalMatrixDistribution[2]]] // N]` so the outer scope's definition will not influence it.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I was testing out the specific expression I wanted in the distribution first, and used the same symbol in `MatrixPropertyDistribution`. Although I don't understand why Mathematica is built this way, since the `x` in the expression is self-contained. To me, it's similar to if you could not define two functions `f[x_]` and `g[x_]` since the two x's would refer to the same thing.